# Cannot convert void to java.lang.Void

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to do the following

```
interface Updater {
    void update(String value);
}

void update(Collection<String> values, Updater updater) {
    update(values, updater::update, 0);
}

void update(Collection<String> values, Function<String, Void> fn, int ignored) {
    // some code
}
```

but I get this compiler error:

```
"Cannot convert void to java.lang.Void"
```

That means `updater::update` cannot be used as `Function<String, Void>`.

Of course I can't write `Function <String, void>` and I don't want to change return type of `update()` to `Void`.

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A `Function` returns a value, even if it is declared as being of type `Void` (you will have to return `null`  then. In contrast, a `void` method really returns nothing, not even `null`. So you have to insert the `return` statement:

```
void update(Collection<String> values, Updater updater) {
    update(values, s -> { updater.update(); return null; }, 0);
}
```

An alternative would be to change the `Function<String,Void>` to `Consumer<String>`, then you can use the method reference:

```
void update(Collection<String> values, Updater updater) {
    update(values, updater::update, 0);
}
void update(Collection<String> values, Consumer<String> fn, int ignored) {
    // some code
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i accept this! P.S. i updated first post, method update() gets String as argument, i just forget about it.

Comment: @Dmitry Ginzburg: the question is tagged with [tag:java-8], what do you want to warn about?

Comment: @Holger Im guessing lamda expressions.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that tag

Comment: I would say this is probably something Java should handle.  And non-returning lambda should be compatible with Function<Object,Void>; the Java compiler should generate code to return null for the lambda.

Answer (score 17):

A function returns a value. What you are looking for is the `java.util.function.Consumer` interface. This has an `void accept(T)` method and doesn't return a value.

So you method becomes:

```
void update(Collection<String> values, Consumer<String> fn, int ignored) {
    // some code
}
```