# void with Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-7, java-17

I have a function that returns void

```
public interface IProductService {
   void delete(String id);
}
```

Generic method

```
public interface IRequestHandler<C , R> {
    R handler(C c);
    Class<C> commandType();
}
```

Implementation of generic interface

```
 @Singleton
    public record DeleteProductCommandHandler(IProductService iProductService)
            implements IRequestHandler<DeleteProductCommand, Void> {


        @Override
        public Void handler(DeleteProductCommand deleteProductCommand) {
            return iProductService.delete(deleteProductCommand.id);
        }

        @Override
        public Class<DeleteProductCommand> commandType() {
            return DeleteProductCommand.class;
        }
    }
```

How can I use void in `IRequestHandler<DeleteProductCommand, Void>` so that I can map void from `iProductService.delete(deleteProductCommand.id);`

Comment: Make the `handler` method to contain two statements: 1) simple `iProductService.delete(...)`; 2) and `return null;`.

Comment: really null is the return type ??

Comment: Null is not the return type; `Void` is.  But there is only one possible value of `Void` -- `null`.   So that's what you return.  (You can understand this by analogy to the other primitive wrappers.  `Integer` has one value that corresponds to each value of `int`, plus the distinguished value `null`.  Same is true for all the primitive wrappers.  Since `void` has no values, `Void` has all (none) of those, plus `null`.)

Comment: @BrianGoetz - Your explanation is a little confusing. It seems I can only return a `null` from a `Void` method. If `Void has all (none) of those, plus null` how come I cannot return any thing such as an `int`?

Comment: @K.Nicholas `Integer` is the reference companion type for `int`.  For every value of `int` (all 2^32) of them, there is a corresponding value of `Integer`, plus `Integer` also can take on the value `null`.  `Void` is the reference companion for `void`.  For every value of `void` (all zero of them), there is a corresponding value of `Void`, plus `Void` can also take on the value `null`.  So `null` is the only valid value of `Void`.  If you wanted to be able to return _anything_, make your return type `Object`.

Comment: @BrianGoetz - Thanks. Sounds like you're using set theory (discrete math?) for your explanation.

Comment: See [Cannot convert void to java.lang.Void](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28762715/2711488)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java generics void/Void types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568409/java-generics-void-void-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option 1:

Just return `null`:

```java
@Override
public Void handler(DeleteProductCommand deleteProductCommand) {
    iProductService.delete(deleteProductCommand.id);
    return null;
}
```

#### Option 2:

Update the `IProductService::delete` method to return something meaningful, e.g. a `boolean` value like `Collection::remove` does:

```java
public interface IProductService {
   boolean delete(String id);
}
```

```java
@Singleton
public record DeleteProductCommandHandler(IProductService iProductService)
            implements IRequestHandler<DeleteProductCommand, Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean handler(DeleteProductCommand deleteProductCommand) {
        return iProductService.delete(deleteProductCommand.id);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<DeleteProductCommand> commandType() {
        return DeleteProductCommand.class;
    }
}
```