# Confusion in overloading println method, in Thread and ExecutorService

Tags: java, overloading

I was reading the `Effective Java edition 3 by Joshua Bloch` in item 52, page 242 I encountered something strange that hope you Java heroes could help me demystify it. I quote exactly from the book:

> The addition of lambdas and method references in Java 8 further
> increased the potential for confusion in overloading. For example,
> consider these two snippets:

```
new Thread(System.out::println).start();

ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
exec.submit(System.out::println);
```

> While the Thread constructor invocation and the submit method
> invocation look similar, the former compiles while the latter does
> not. The arguments are identical (System.out::println), and both the
> constructor and the method have an overloading that takes a Runnable.
> What’s going on here?
> The surprising answer is that the submit method has an overloading
> that takes a Callable, while the Thread constructor does not. You
> might think that this shouldn’t make any difference because all overloadings of println
> return void, so the method reference couldn’t possibly be a Callable.
> This makes perfect sense, but it’s not the way the overload resolution
> algorithm works. Perhaps equally surprising is that the submit method
> invocation would be legal if the println method weren’t also
> overloaded. It is the combination of the overloading of the referenced
> method (println) and the invoked method (submit) that prevents the
> overload resolution algorithm from behaving as you’d expect.

and author goes by giving the technical reason why the second method would not compile.  again I didn't understand!

> the problem is that System.out::println is an inexact method reference
> [JLS, 15.13.1] and that “certain argument expressions that contain
> implicitly typed lambda expressions or inexact method references are
> ignored by the applicability tests, because their meaning cannot be
> determined until a target type is selected [JLS, 15.12.2].”

when I tried the `ExecutorService` example in IDE(Intellij), it gave me this error:

```
reference to 'println' is ambiguous both 'println()' and 'println(boolean)' match
```

If I apply the following change the compile time error goes away.
*how this cast clarifies the ambiguity?*

```
Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit((Runnable) System.out::println);
```

my questions are first what is going on here, and second why IDE reported confusion between `println()` and `println(boolean)`. `Callable` and `Runnable` don't want input parameters so by `System.out::println` we definitely mean `println()` in this context.

Comment: @Abra you are right, but we used method reference in a context that requires `Callable` or `Runnable` and they both don't require input parameters.

Comment: IntelliJ's message is likely an IntelliJ bug. `javac` doesn't say that. Instead it properly says that it can't figure out which of the two `submit`s you want to call.

Comment: What don't you understand about the technical reason that the author gave?

Comment: @Sweeper about Intellij you are right thanks a lot. I don't understand this part. *The surprising answer is that the submit method has an overloading that takes a Callable, while the Thread constructor does not. You might think that this shouldn’t make any difference because all overloadings of println return void, so the method reference couldn’t possibly be a Callable* here author explains why there should not be an ambiguity then he gave the technical reason why ambiguity exists. I can't understand the technical reason mainly.

Comment: By the way, if experimenting with this example code, beware: Output from `System.out.println` does *not* necessarily appear on the console in chronological order, when called across threads. As a workaround, include and study timestamps, ex: `Instant.now()` or `System.nanoTime()`.

Comment: `void` has a `Void` pair, and thus `Callable<Void>` exists, and can't be told apart from `Runnable` in this implicit situation. That's what you resolve by explicitly specifying one of the two.

Comment: @tevemadar interesting. I couldn't reconcile your explanation with this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762715/cannot-convert-void-to-java-lang-void can you elaborate more?